# Can't install NVIDIA driver cause of login loop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login

I have some problems with rendering in Chromium-based browsers, so, I decided to install proprietary Nvidia drivers. I have this two options in Software & Updates:

[image]

When I chose one of this two options I had got login loop. I had to remove it manually and install:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia\*
sudo apt install nvidia-304 # or nvidia-340
```

After reboot I got login loop again. The content of `.xsession-errors` is

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2668) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2661) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (2391) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2453) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2659) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (2721) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (2726) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (2728) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-keyboard main process (2729) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-printers main process (2733) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (2734) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2680) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-sound main process (2730) killed by TERM signal
```

P.S. `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` is owned by my user.

Now I switched to X.Org drivers but I would like to install Nvidia. How?
My system is Ubuntu 16.04.5

**UPD:** `nvidia-prime` package does not help

**UPD:** Guest session does not work too

**UPD:** Problem is still exists after last kernel update

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 I do not have Secure Boot

Comment: Looks like unsupported hardware in the binary driver.  I'ld check the blacklist in modprobe.d and see if your card is blacklisted.  Someone else may have more input, as I don't have this card.  Also, I run AMD cards, so an lspci output blob might be useful to find someone that has the exact same card.

Comment: @RobotHumans thanks for answer. The strange think is that I did it on this laptop but a couple years ago with another Ubuntu version. Now I have been using current installation of Ubuntu 16.04 for 1 year with Nouveau drivers. Will try to check blacklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVIDIA support helped to resolve the issue:

1. Remove previous driver installation attempts:

   `sudo apt purge nvidia-\*`
2. Blacklist the open source nouveau driver

   `echo "blacklist nouveau\nblacklist lbm-nouveau" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf`

   `sudo update-initramfs -u`
3. `sudo reboot`
4. Download the current driver from here: http://www.nvidia.com
5. Open Terminal and stop X server:

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

   `sudo service lightdm stop`
6. `sudo sh <driver_name>`

if you get a message that the pre-install script failed, select 'continue'

8. when completed, reboot